# how to calculate nr of appointments between specific time periods in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, time

I want to create a dataframe where I sum the number of appointments every week (weeks starting on Sunday and finishing on Saturday) from 29-11-2015 up until 05-09-2020.

First, I calculated the number of appointments per day as per below, but now I am struggling to jump to the next exercise - to do it per week. Do you know of a quick way to do this?

```
appointments_day <- df %>%
       group_by(region, id, name, date) %>%
       summarise(appointments = n())
  expand.grid(date = seq(min(df$date), max(df$date), by = '1 day')) %>%
       left_join(., appointments_day)
```

My dataset is:

```
region   id      name        date       appointments
   A      1    clinic1    29-11-2015         2
   A      1    clinic1    26-05-2020         1
   A      1    clinic1    28-05-2020         4
   A      1    clinic1    01-06-2020         2
   A      1    clinic1    03-06-2020         2
   A      2    clinic2    25-05-2020         3
   A      2    clinic2    26-05-2020         1
   A      2    clinic2    27-05-2020         4
   B      3    clinic3    06-07-2020         3
   B      3    clinic3    08-07-2020         2
   B      3    clinic3    09-07-2020         1
```

I want to create the following dataset:

```
    region   id      name        first day of the week (as Sunday)     appointments
       A      1    clinic1            29-11-2015                            2
....
       A      1    clinic1            24-05-2020                            5
       A      1    clinic1            31-05-2020                            4    
....
       A      2    clinic2            29-11-2015                            0
....
       A      2    clinic2            24-05-2020                            8
....
       B      3    clinic3            29-11-2015                            0
....
       B      3    clinic3            05-07-2020                            6
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your dataset I would do the following:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

df <- setDT(your_dataset)

df$date <- dmy(df$date)
df$week_year <- paste0(week(df$date), '-', year(df$date))

result <- df[, .(appointments = .N), by = .(region, id, name, week_year)]
```

(You don't have to aggregate the dates for each day first. You could use my code for the original dataset)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I get date = NA and week_year NA-NA if I run your code in my original dataset which has more columns that the example I put in my question btw. Also, I dont know where you have specified in your code that my weeks go from Sundays-Saturdays and from 29-11-2015 up until 05-09-2020?

Comment: Did you import the library lubridate?

Comment: Yes. I get date = NA and week_year NA-NA in "df" and in "result" I get week_year=NA-NA and appointments seem to be the total for each clinic, which is not want I need. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, maybe your date column is already formatted as Date. Try to leave the dmy() out. Obviously if there is no information in the date column it can't separate the groups correctly, therefore you see total appointments for each clinic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be working. When you do "week(df$Date)" - this function week starts on Sunday? Do you know? I need to be certain of this. Also one last thing, this function week starts counting from the initial date there is for a clinic, but I have to put missing weeks from 29-11-2015 equal to 0, do you know how to do this?

Comment: I think it would worth to ask this as a separate question. I don't know how to fill in missing weeks or dates.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I think your solution does not meet what I need. the week function "returns the number of complete seven day periods that have occurred between the date and January 1st, plus one." which will vary from one year to the other. I need my count of weeks to start from Sunday (from 29-11-2015). Thanks for your time on this!